# Setting new text file line delimiter as Unix in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 running on Microsoft WindowsServer 2008 R2. Now I want set "New File Line Delimiter" as Unix (or set as default for all work spaces) for all users.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 5):

Workspace: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> New text file line delimiter.

Project: Properties -> Resource -> New text file line delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for answer, But as i have mentioned here, I have one eclipse DUMP in server running with multiple Work spaces, So i want to be change the eclipse default for "New File Line Delimiter" for all work spaces as "UNIX"

Comment: Sorry, but you question isn't all that clear. I don't know how to override the Eclipse default if you create a new workspace. However, the [ETE](http://pellaton.github.com/eclipse-team-etceteras/index.html) plugin allows you to store default workspace preferences somewhere an whenever a new workspace is created it asks the user whether he wants to load those default preferences. Hence, you can do much more than just set the line delimiter. I highly recommend that plugin.

Comment: New link for ETE plugin: https://netceteragroup.github.io/eclipse-team-etceteras/

Answer (score 0):

The file dilimeter I was looking for separated lines of code from obvious sharp differences in the data (e.g. 1. "," , 2. ":", 3. ";" , etc.).  I did find my answer using the following line of code:

```
 String arr[ ] = line.split(",");

              OR

 String arr[ ] = line.split(":");
```